# How to make Woocommerce not to save Checkout billing fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a particular case where I need many people to login to ONE specially created user (one login name and one password for all) and purchase items through it. The problem is if Person A logins with this ONE user credentials and makes a purchase he will leave a trace in shipping/billing details, person B will then see those details when in checkout page. Woocommerce saves those details by default, how could I disable that? How can I make Woocommerce Chechout page to always have empty fields with no prepopulated data from previous purchases?

Thanks!
Mantas

[image]

Comment: If you modify the form-billing.php template (please follow best practices and put the template in your theme directory `your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php` you **could** strip out the part that fills in the values.

Comment: Hi cale, thanks I've tried doing that but I can't see where in the file I can achieve that https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-billing.php ? I'm not able to track whre exactly these values are called

Comment: Ok, so I've commented out $checkout->get_value( $key ) in form billing and in form-shipping files, that seemed to work but now the values don't get saved to order details, no way to know where to ship...

Comment: Great!  Now the only problem I think you will find is if you fill it out incomplete, and "fail" validation, you probably will NOT be presented back with the info you provided earlier.

Comment: Person B should only see Person A's details if logged in as Person A.

Comment: Hi cale_b actually the validation works fine and all the details are present after validation error but the details now are not saved to Order information which is important for Admin to see :/ It's like this commenting out causes woocommerce to not save the details at all, even when I update Woo templates to default there's still no info in the order, nothing was saved. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need this filter... this filter is meant to overwrite the values being displayed at checkout... below will return empty string... to empty the values being displayed.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string',10);
```

But this does not mean, these values won't be seen in other places.. like "My Account" page..

Comment: Hi, thanks for this :) But now these details are not saved at all, nothing in My Account page and nothing in Order information. I would have unhooked address details in My account page anyways but I need shipping details to go to Order details for the Admin to see. Can it be that this filter also causes woocommerce to not save the entered details at all?

Comment: no, I have tried it... and that filter is just used for display... for "getting" values and not for "setting"...

Comment: try a fresh install of wordpress and woocommerce in your localhost to test... and use that filter... something in your codes or other plugins might be the one not letting you save the data..

Comment: @Mantas you can also try to add and/or remove this filter in your codes... see if this filter is really the problem...

Comment: my apologies, I've reactivated woocommerce plugin and this seemed to refresh my previous edits. Now it works as it should, thanks so much!