# Woocommerce never save shipping address on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

By default Woocommerce saves the billing and shipping address on the checkout page.

I am searching for a way to prevent Woocommerce from saving the values in the shipping address. So all the fields in the **shipping address** should be empty.

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318793/how-to-make-woocommerce-not-to-save-checkout-billing-fields) I found a partial solution. It works great, but it also makes the billing address empty:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string',10);
```

Is there a way to do this only for shipping address?

Big thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the code like this...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'reigel_empty_checkout_shipping_fields', 10, 2 );
function reigel_empty_checkout_shipping_fields( $value, $input ) {
    /*
    Method 1
    you can check the field if it has 'shipping_' on it...
    if ( strpos( $input, 'shipping_' ) !== FALSE ) {
        $value = '';
    }

    Method 2
    put all the fields you want in an array...
    */
    $shipping_fields = array(
        //'shipping_first_name',
        //'shipping_last_name',
        'shipping_company',
        'shipping_country',
        'shipping_address_1',
        'shipping_address_2',
        'shipping_city',
        'shipping_state',
        'shipping_country',
        'shipping_postcode'
    );

    if ( in_array( $input, $shipping_fields ) ) {
        $value = '';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! How did you know / find out you can add these variables ($input, $value) as parameters to the function reigel_empty_checkout_shipping_fields ? Does this have something to do with the filter you are calling? Thank you.

Comment: look for `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` in woocommerce files